# Is there a way to use an unordered pair as a rust Hashmap key?

Tags: rust

Let's say I have to store the cost of traversal between nodes in a non directed graph. I'd like to have a HashMap that uses pairs of `String` or `&str` as keys and `u32` as values. Is there a data container that can be used as key such that `map.get(container("a","b")) == map.get(container("b", "a"))`?

Comment: How could this question be improved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on what at54321 said, you can implement an "unordered pair" type that enforces a consistent order, effectively making (a, b) and (b, a) equal values.  Using this as the map's key type will prevent any possibility of accidentally looking up a pair with the larger value first.

This means that `ref_a()` may not return the first value passed to the constructor.  This type implements `From<(T, T)>`, so if ordering is needed in other parts of the application you can continue to use a tuple and use `.into()` when interacting with a map.

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};

struct UnorderedPair<T> {
    a: T,
    b: T,
}

impl<T: Ord> UnorderedPair<T> {
    pub fn new(a: T, b: T) -> Self {
        if a < b {
            Self { a, b }
        } else {
            Self { a: b, b: a }
        }
    }
    
    pub fn ref_a(&self) -> &T {
        &self.a
    }
    
    pub fn ref_b(&self) -> &T {
        &self.b
    }
}

impl<T: Ord> From<(T, T)> for UnorderedPair<T> {
    fn from(t: (T, T)) -> Self {
        Self::new(t.0, t.1)
    }
}

impl<T: PartialEq<T>> PartialEq<UnorderedPair<T>> for UnorderedPair<T> {
    fn eq(&self, rhs: &Self) -> bool {
        self.a == rhs.a && self.b == rhs.b
    }
}

impl<T: Eq> Eq for UnorderedPair<T> { }

impl<T: PartialOrd> PartialOrd for UnorderedPair<T> {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, rhs: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        match self.a.partial_cmp(&rhs.a) {
            Some(Ordering::Equal) => self.b.partial_cmp(&rhs.b),
            v => v,
        }
    }
}

impl<T: Ord> Ord for UnorderedPair<T> {
    fn cmp(&self, rhs: &Self) -> std::cmp::Ordering {
        match self.a.cmp(&rhs.a) {
            Ordering::Equal => self.b.cmp(&rhs.b),
            v => v,
        }
    }
}

impl<T: Hash> Hash for UnorderedPair<T> {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, hasher: &mut H) {
        self.a.hash(hasher);
        self.b.hash(hasher);
    }
}
```

Then, for example:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    
    map.insert(UnorderedPair::new("a", "b"), "c");
    
    assert_eq!(map.get(&("a", "b").into()), Some(&"c"));
    assert_eq!(map.get(&("b", "a").into()), Some(&"c"));
    assert_eq!(map.get(&("a", "a").into()), None);
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=201033c63b3e20bcf6255c70ec128b06))

Comment: The implementation of `PartialEq` [must be consistent with](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hash/trait.Hash.html#hash-and-eq) the `Hash` impl. So you need to change it to: `self.a == rhs.a && self.b == rhs.b || self.a == rhs.b && self.b == rhs.a`.

Comment: And, for that reason, I don't think you can implement `Ord` for `UnorderedPair` (because `Ord` and  `Eq` must also be consistent or else you will break BTrees).

Comment: @PeterHall I'm not sure how that could be violated in my implementation as `a` and `b` are forced into an order in `new()`. `self.a <= self.b` is an invariant of this type. ... Except that mutation is possible -- I need to remove the mut accessors. Edit: Mut accessors are gone.

Comment: Oh I see. That does make your code correct then. However it is probably not what OP wants  - i.e. you might swap the values over in the getters vs what they specified in the constructor.

Comment: That is, `ref_a()` actually returns the "lesser" of the two values, not the value of `a` that was given to the constructor.

Comment: @PeterHall Correct, but that should be an expected possibility from a type that is called "unordered." :) If we want an "ordered-but-compares-as-unordered" type, that is something else that could be similarly implemented.

Comment: Just because you don't need to consider ordering for the purpose of using the values as a HashMap key, does not mean that you _never_ want to consider their order anywhere else in your application.

Comment: Sure. If that's needed then we can just add `From<(T, T)>` to this type and `(T, T)` can be the type used elsewhere in the program. The point of using this type as the key was to ensure that in the map, the order is always consistent. If order is needed elsewhere then a different type should be used there.

Comment: I've implemented `From<(T, T)>` to assist with this possible use case.

Comment: I think I'd find it more intuitive if your type kept the order of `a` and `b` the same, but `Eq` and `Hash` were implemented such that the order didn't matter. Your wrapper could even be a newtype.

Comment: @cdhowie, I took your playground example and made a version with what I would consider a truly unordered pair which maintains the position of each item without ordering any guarantees. However, it does have the downside of needing to determine an ordering whenever it needs to perform an action. [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ab9c9bb27bcbf9a8a540828f15266260).

Comment: @Locke A "truly unordered pair" doesn't have to maintain ordering because... it's not ordered. What you're talking about is an ordered pair that pretends to be unordered when compared. This is why I provided `From<(T, T)>` in my example -- `(T, T)` is the ordered type, `UnorderedPair<T>` is the unordered type. You use `(T, T)` where order is important and you `.into()` an unordered pair when needed, which will only perform the comparison `a < b` once. It's both more performant and more semantically correct.

Comment: @cdhowie I think of an unordered pair as differing from an N=2 set by maintaining unordered slots that items can be placed in without providing any guarantees of what those slots may contain in relevance to each other. If you spend the compute time to order every pair on creation, then it somewhat defeats the purpose of using an unordered pair to begin with. That being said, it makes less sense in the context of a hashmap since you know that every entry will need to have its order checked to place it into the map anyway so you will lose the benefits of the delayed comparison.

Comment: @Locke To me a container that preserves order is ordered, so the concept of an unordered pair always preserving the order of the components seems like a contradiction.

Comment: @cdhowie We may be straying into theoretical computer science now. Technically speaking I think you might be right in that regard. My version was ordered and unsorted, but yours was unordered and sorted. That being said, I think we might have been overlooked the initial question. Since the author mentions that they are creating a directed graph, order does matter so the question isn't quite right. The goal appears more related to a creating a map in the domain of undirected edges onto T using only directed edges keys.

Comment: @Locke Right, so they should be using `(T, T)` to notate edges in their structure, and use `UnorderedPair<T>` for the lookup map.

Answer (score 3):

In such cases I think it's usually best to simply use a consistent order of the strings in the pair. Let's say you have a tuple `(s1, s2)`. If you always put the smaller string first, then everything will work as expected. Example: `("foo", "bar")` and `("bar", "foo")` will always be represented the same way, as `("bar", "foo")`.

You can implement a custom container type that does that for you or you can simply have a helper function like this:

```
fn as_key<'a>(s1: &'a str, s2: &'a str) -> (&'a str, &'a str) {
    if s1 < s2 {
        (s1, s2)
    } else {
        (s2, s1)
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", as_key("foo", "bar"));  // Prints ("bar", "foo")
    println!("{:?}", as_key("bar", "foo"));  // Prints ("bar", "foo")
}
```

If you only have a few places where you work with the map, using a helper function like the above `as_key` will probably be the simplest solution, but you mustn't forget to call it each time you need to pass a key to the map. Using a custom type would require a bit more code, but it would be safer.